# How to shuffle a Hashtable in java

Tags: java, class, dictionary, hashtable, shuffle

I have a constructor in a class, where I initialise a hashtable, consisting of an Integer and a list of Strings. I fill the keys with numbers from 0 to whatever is needed and their corresponding values are Vectors that I create in the constructor beforehand. What I need is to rearrange them randomly (just shuffle them in any way possible), so that when I use getQuest() I will get a random key-value pair that has happened to be on the last spot of the hashtable and delete it at the same time.

```
public class Quest {

private Hashtable<Integer, List<String>> quests;

public Quest()
{
    this.quests = new Hashtable<>();
    List<String> mushrooms = new Vector<>();
    mushrooms.add("Choose a mushroom, but be careful not to be poisoned");
    mushrooms.add("mushroom1");
    mushrooms.add("mushroom2");
    mushrooms.add("mushroom3");
    List<String> weapons = new Vector<>();
    weapons.add("Choose a weapon that will help you survive");
    weapons.add("knife");
    weapons.add("rifle");
    weapons.add("sword");
    this.quests.put(0, mushrooms);
    this.quests.put(1, weapons);
}

public List<String> getQuest()
{
    return quests.remove(quests.size());

}
}
```

Also, in case this is not a good idea, is it better to use rand or something like that and get a random pair from somewhere in the hashtable to return (while also deleting it, of course).

Comment: Side note: `Hashtable` and `Vector` have been outdated since Java 1.3. Consider using `HashMap` and `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t “shuffle” a `Hashtable` or `Map` - the elements are not ordered.

That said, an `iterator` will generally return the same order each time, so in order to change that, put the keys into an `ArrayList` and use `Collections.shuffle` on that. Iterate over that shuffled list and access the elements in the table/map via their key.

Comment: @Krease Just out of curiosity since HashTable use hashing and elements will be stored based on there key's hashcode. So can't we override hashcode method to achieve the different order?

Comment: @Gaurav - ***Do NOT try to override hashCode to control HashMap iteration order***. In theory, _maybe possible_, but it would be incredibly fragile code that any sane developer should not do. (Huge extra complexity to that implementation of `hashCode`, tightly dependent on the exact implementation of `HashMap` iteration, impacted by bucket resizing, high potential to accidentally break `equals` contract, likely increased hash collisions, etc, etc). Repeating just for clarity: ***Do NOT try to override hashCode to control HashMap iteration order***.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list instead of a hashtable, and remove an item at a random index.

Also, if doing it your way, this line:

```
return quests.remove(quests.size());
```

should be

```
return quests.remove(quests.size()-1);
```

You might also want to check if quests.size() > 0...

Comment: Yeah, that is probably a good idea. My plan at the beginning was a little different from now and I kind of messed up my logic. Thanks.